# windows режет фотографии при печати

Tags: windows, печать

Windows 10 режет фотографии при печати на принтере Canon LBP6030W, jpg, bmp, png и пр. режет, а документы .doc .xls и пр. нет. из windows и paint.net режет из Photoshop и paint нет. изображения размером более 1000 пикселей режет, а менее 1000 пикселей не режет. с самого ПК печатает обрезая, но с виртуальной машины (средствами windows) на подключенном по локальной сети принтере печатает норм.

[image: пытаюсь распечатать это:]
[image: получаю это:]

Comment: Когда печатаете "средствами Windows" проверьте, чтобы не была установлена галка "Изображение по размеру кадра": https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qsJ6.png

Comment: insolor, пробовал и с ней и без нее, эффекта нет.

Comment: проблема решилась обновлением windows, но не надолго, на сутки, и снова все так же.... может кто знает как решить проблему?

Comment: попробуйте переустановить принтер, и посмотреть что там с дровами, и плюс попробуйте картинку конвертировать в пдф для пробы и его распечатать

Comment: Andrew, переустанавливал драйвера, не помогло, преобразованную картинку в pdf печатает нормально.... Пробовал снова обновить windows, в этот раз не помогло.

Comment: та же проблема, пытаюсь найти настройки, в которых изображение перед печатью обрабатывается не принтером, а компьютером. И кстати, печатает нормально с помощью программ печати, типа Эпсон Фото принт(принтер Эпсон).

Comment: Такая же проблема, принтер Brother, но проблема не в принтере и не в драйверах, а именно в стандартном приложении "печать изображений", т.к. даже при печати с предпросмотром образка идет на предпросмотре, а любые другие программы использующие другой движок печати не имеют никаких проблем (даже стандартная программа "фотографии" печатает из своего движка без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Я знаю о подобной проблеме связанной с установкой обновлений [KB4560960](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-9-2020-kb4560960-os-builds-18362-900-and-18363-900-8b5edf81-eed0-11b1-f26a-d905e19e88de) и [KB4557957](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-9-2020-kb4557957-os-build-19041-329-cdba3c41-dc73-8e5a-df2e-795cf01cc2b7). Если они у вас установлены, то просто откатите до одной из предыдущих версий. С некоторыми принтерами помогает переустановка драйверов. Ну или как советуют в комментариях - печатайте из другого приложения.
У меня ещё из-за этих обновлений не получается сканировать больше в официальном приложении Samsung для моего принтера, а вот в других - получается.

Да, интересный момент: насколько я знаю, майкрософт до сих пор отрицает этот баг (я про него услышал летом прошлого года, в июне-июле). И скорее-всего фикса не будет в обозримом будущем.

UPD как подсказал Alex Alex - уже признали проблему, так что может и выпустят фикс. Хотя признавали 9 месяцев, так что кто знает.

UPD2: Вроде бы обновление KB5001649 должно исправлять проблему. Вышло вчера.

Comment: Да, вы правы, вот еще обсуждение такой проблемы: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/546834/